# AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run a Scrapy spider and dump it all into a json file. Here's my code:

```
import scrapy
import re


class MissleItem(scrapy.Item):

    missle_name = scrapy.Field()
    missle_type = scrapy.Field()
    missle_origin = scrapy.Field()
    missle_range = scrapy.Field()
    missle_comments = scrapy.Field()



class missleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'missle_list'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/...']


    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('///div/table[2]/tbody')
        rows = table.xpath('//tr')
        row = rows[2]
        row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract()

        for row in response.xpath('// \
        [@class="wikitable"]//tbody//tr'):

            name = {
            'Missle' : row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Type': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Origin' : 
            row.xpath('td[3]/a//text()').extract_first(), 
            'Range': 
            row.xpath('td[4]//text()').replace(u'\&nbsp;', u' 
            ').extract_first(),  
            'Comments' : 
            row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first()}


            yield MissleItem(missle_name=name['Missle'], 
                            missle_type=name['Type'], 
                            missle_origin=name['Origin'], 
                            missle_range=name['Range'], 
                            missle_comments=name['Comments'])
```

When I run the previous code, I get:
    AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'replace'

My question is, how can I return my Range Column without the 'nbsp;' extra output? I tried:

```
'Range': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').strip().extract_first()
```

But then I got a:

```
AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
row.xpath('td[4]//text()').replace(u'\&nbsp;', u'').extract_first(),
```

try to put the `extract_first()` before replace attribute